# Definition and proposition about a left-invariant of Poisson structure

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, poisson-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $e$ its unite element  and let $\pi$ be an bivector filed, do we have that the following are equivalent:

1. $\pi$ is left-invariant Poisson structure.i.e, for all $g\in G$:
   $$\pi(L^*_g\alpha,L^*_g\beta)  =\pi(\alpha,\beta) \circ L_g$$ where  $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega^1(G)$.
2. for all $g\in G$:
   $$ \pi_{\#,g} = T_eL_g\circ \pi_{\#,e}\circ(T_eL_g)^*$$
   more details, ($T_gG \stackrel{(T_eL_g)^*}{\longrightarrow} T_e^*G \stackrel{\pi_{\#,e}}{\longrightarrow} T_e^*G \stackrel{T_eL_g}{\longrightarrow} T_g^*G$ ),then the map $\pi_{\#,g} :  T^*_gG \longrightarrow T_gG$
3. $\forall$ $g\in G$ $\forall \; \varphi\; \psi \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(G)$
   $$ \{ \varphi \circ L_g, \psi \circ L_g\} = \{\varphi,\psi\}\circ L_g $$
4. if G is connected, for any $u\in \mathcal{G}$(lie algebra),
   $$L_u \pi =0 $$

where $L_g :G \longrightarrow G $ is the left translation on $G$.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: yes, l need some helps to prove the equivalent  between 1,2,3,4

Comment: Have you tried unraveling the definitions carefully for the first 3 statements at least?

Comment: Hi, T.P,  I've tried a lot, I think I'm missing some definitions and a rule, do you have some ideas?

Comment: Assume statement 1 holds and take two 1-forms and plug them into the right hand side of the equation in statement 2. What would this give you? For statement 3, think of exact 1-forms and see how this is related to statement 1. It should be straightforward.